# intersect function for arrays in pl sql

Tags: plsql

I am trying to find the intersection result between two arrays in sql.

Also i have a small doubt in the below code is that i have written y.extend(32000).
If i remove his line i get limit error. I have only 9 records though in my 2d array.

Because of extend function i am unable to get current count in the array i.e y.count results 32000

The demo code is given as follows:

```
DECLARE
  type items is table of number;
  type item_sets is table of items;
  y item_sets;
  i number := 0;
  v_c items;
  cursor c1 is
    select distinct item from sales_demo order by item;
BEGIN
  y := item_sets();
  y.EXTEND(32000);
  FOR Z IN c1 LOOP
    i := i + 1;
    SELECT tid bulk collect into y(i) FROM sales_demo WHERE item = z.item;  
  END LOOP;
  v_c := y(1) multiset intersect y(2); -- i want intersection result between y1 and y2
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE((v_c).count);
END;
```

Any help will be useful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH Y1 AS (SELECT TID
              FROM SALES_DEMO
              WHERE ITEM = (SELECT LEAST(ITEM)
                              FROM SALES_DEMO))
WITH Y2 AS (SELECT TID
              FROM SALES_DEMO
              WHERE ITEM = (SELECT *
                              FROM (SELECT ITEM
                                      FROM SALES_DEMO
                                      WHERE ITEM > LEAST(ITEM)
                                      ORDER BY ITEM)
                              WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
SELECT *
  FROM Y1
  INTERSECT Y2
```

This avoids all the mucking about with arrays and such, and lets the database do what it's good at.

Share and enjoy.